# Unable to enter User name and password in IE 11 using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wanted to pass user name and password to a URL using Selenium
I tried the below logic

1) Pass username and password in the URL ie) http://Uname:pwd@url.com
2) Using alert and setAuthenticationCredentials

In the first approach the url is not getting redirected. Browser is initiated and that's it.
In the second approach, the login popup is displayed. But its not entering the username and password. When I run the script in debug mode, the code is not reaching driver.switchto().alert();
In the gotoURL only its struck.
I am using IE11 in Windows 10
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AN8u5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your first option, namely passing the credentials in the URL, this blog post provides a way forward:

https://blog.ham1.co.uk/2016/03/05/selenium-allow-basic-auth-in-ie11/

1. You need to create the following nodes in the registry:

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet 
   Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet 
   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE
2. Create keys for “iexplore.exe” and “explorer.exe”
3. And set both to a DWORD with a value of 0

it is definitely the second prize for me, it deviates from the way an actual user would have interacted with the site under test.

I have also found out that the Basic Authentication method is no longer supported by the Webdriver, it will not work on Java at all. It still works on .net, but only on Win7-8.1.